# When is a temporary tablespace used?

Tags: sql, oracle

In which cases a temporary tablespace is required?
It's mentioned in Oracle documentation but I do not understand why it's being used.

I'm using Oracle 12c r2

Thanks in advance, Petar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary tablespaces are used in many places. But a simple example might be a SORT operation that is too big to fit into memory. In the case, the sort "spills" to TEMP - basically the temporary tablespace is used to hold some of the sort segments while the sort takes place in memory.
This is just one of many examples.

Comment: Another example is when joining two tables; depending on the join method, Oracle may need to keep data around temporarily to do that join.

Comment: Also used for temporary tables, including the internal ones used when a query needs to temporarily materialise a result set.